# .gitconfig alias function call

Tags: git

I have defined the following alias in my .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    teamcity = ! tc
```

`tc` is a shell function I defined in my `.bashrc` file.  For some reason, I get the following error:

```
[aafghani-03:~/git/workday amirafghani(master)]$ git teamcity
 tc: tc: command not found
```

Anyone know what I can do to solve this?  I'm trying to keep the function in my `.bashrc`
file if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it like so

```
git config alias.teamcity '!bash -ic tc'
```

<sub>*This won't work when the alias is defined outside the bash startup files. But you clearly state it's in .bashrc, so you're good*</sub>

Comment: This won't work as expected if arguments are passed to `git teamcity`.  You probably want something like this instead:  `git config alias.teamcity '!bash -ic '\''tc "$@"'\'' -'`

Comment: This runs much more quickly for me: `git config alias.teamcity '!source ${HOME}/.bash_aliases && tc'`. But you'd have to define your aliases in ~/.bash_aliases.