# git log since yesterday for working days only

Tags: git, agile, logging

For my daily standups I like to output my commits for a refresher of what I was working on.

I have the following alias:

```
standup = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(green)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --committer='me' --all --since='yesterday'
```

However this does not work for a Monday morning due to the weekend.

Does anyone know how to use `git log --since` for a set of working days such as Mon - Fri, or Tue - Sat?

Comment: what is that --committerk option? I have --committer on my gitlog, but it doesn't recognise 'me' as a replacement for my user.name

Comment: That was a typo I have corrected above.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming a POSIX-y shell, in my case bash:

```
function yesterworkday() 
{ 
    if [[ "1" == "$(date +%u)" ]]
    then 
        echo "last friday"
    else
        echo "yesterday"
    fi
}

git log --since="$(yesterworkday)"
```

Again all credits go to the authors of `git` for making this insanely easy *by accepting "last friday" as a valid date specification* to begin with!

*PS*. to make this a  git alias, you need to include bash shell in your alias, I'll edit with a sample in a minute

**Edit** Putting this logic directly into a git alias proves difficult (with all the quoting required). See here for ideas: [.gitconfig alias function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499508/gitconfig-alias-function-call/6499587#6499587)

I fully recommend making a shell script of this, and you could alias the shell script directly like so:

```
standup = !$HOME/standuplog.sh
```

or add to one of your `$PATH` folders and name it `git-standup`.

Comment: It will be more universal if you use `%u` flag instead `%a` which return trnslated day of the week so won't work for non-English users (like me).

Comment: @sehe - nope. If you use `%u` then `1` is monday.

Comment: Can be updated to use "last friday.midnight" and "yesterday.midnight" to make it time independent. I think otherwise, it will be dependent on when you run the command. If you run it at 10 am today, you might not see any commits you made before 10 am yesterday.

Comment: This can be added as an git alias like so:
```standup = !git  log --since=$([[ "1" == "$(date +%u)" ]] && echo last-friday || echo yesterday)```